# Disabling auto reconnect in MySQL client

Tags: mysql

I am trying to disable the auto reconnect feature in MySQL client by updating the `my.cnf` with `reconnect=false` in the `[client]` section of `my.cnf`. So the `my.cnf` looks something like this:

```
[mysqld]
...
interactive_timeout=30
[client]
port=3306
socket=~/dir/mysql.sock
reconnect=false
```

This is not working. The client times out after 30 secs but reconnects to the server.

While debugging the issue I found that the MySQL client variables are not getting set. 
When I ran the `<dir of mysql>/bin/mysql --help`, I see that the value of `port`, `socket` and `reconnect` flag is :

```
./mysql --help

port                              0
reconnect                         TRUE
socket                            (No default value)
```

I dont want to set the `skip-reconnect` from the command line. I can guess that the client configurations from `my.cnf` are not being exported to the client. But i need a definitive solution.

The problem is some times not replicable. There are some machines in which the change in `my.cnf` works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that `my.cnf` is the one being read? Can you see it when you do `mysql --help --verbose | grep -A1 Default.options` ? Have you tried `mysql --print-defaults` to see what settings you get? Is there another file (e.g. `~/.my.cnf`) overwriting that setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you go through this ? [Controlling Automatic Reconnection Behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html)